# How to use documents and collections Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Im new to firebase and I need help understanding how to work with documents and collections. Specifically I want to be able to write to a document and let it hold an array of 'loan objects' and let it be specific per user. All of these documents will  be held in a collection. This code is making multiple documents for one user and I want it to only make one document per user and if I want to add more data for that user I just want to add it to the existing document

```
const loansRef = firebase.firestore().collection('goals')
useEffect(() => {
    getPW()
    let isMounted = true;

    if (isMounted) {
        loansRef.where('authorID', '==', userId).orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').onSnapshot(
            (querySnapshot) => {
                const newGoals = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    const goal = doc.data();
                    goal.id = doc.id + goalCounter.toString();
                    newGoals.push(goal);
                });
                console.log('new Goals: '+ newGoals)
                console.log('old goals: '+ oldGoals)
             // this is my attempt to try to make all loans appear in one array
                var oldGoals = courseGoals
                for(let j =0; j < newGoals.length; j++){
                    oldGoals.push(newGoals[j])
                }
                setCourseGoals(oldGoals);
                setGoalCounter(goalCounter+1)
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }
    return () => {
        isMounted = false;
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: What you're asking here is too broad for Stack Overflow.  The Firestore [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) contains some great information for learning how to read and write Firestore documents.  Start there.  If you have specific problems with your code, please post the code along with a description of what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've uploaded my code right now; It makes a new document every time I decide to make new 'loans'

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what is not working the way you expect.  The description matters.  You probably don't want to just ask for general help - make your question about the code itself.

Comment: @DougStevenson I did that; hoefully that helps a bit more. Than you for all pointers

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  The code you're showing here isn't creating any documents at all.  It's just making a query for documents.

Comment: wait what? Really? Dang it I got help from a video but I didn't understand the code and they didn't explain it. Thank you so much